# React - nothing is returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problems with my private route (admin). Here's how it looks like:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { user } = rest.user

  return (
    user.length
    ? (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={ props => {
          user[0].tier > 1
          ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/app/unauthorized',
            }}
          />
          )
        }}
      />
      ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
        pathname: '/app/unauthorized',
        }}
      />
    )
  )
}
```

When user is logged and has specific privileges this route should have returned component that is sent as a props like this:

```
<PrivateRoute path={`${url}/`} component={ AdminDashboard } />
```

But I got an error that nothing is returned from render function. Am I missing something obiovus?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Is user defined?

Comment: Yes, user is defined. I'm getting "ncaught Invariant Violation: Route(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null"

Comment: Code smell :). I'm thinking maybe you could simplify it a bit and add some if statements to make it more readable and easy to figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: Apart from the `return` problem I'm not quite sure `const { user } = rest.user;` is what you want here. If `rest` object has a `user` and it also has a `user` then it is ok, but if not then you should use `const { user } = rest;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget to return render method inside Route follow bellow code

```
 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { user } = rest.user

  return (
    user.length
    ? (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={ props => 
          user[0].tier > 1
          ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/app/unauthorized',
            }}
          />
          )
        }
      />
      ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
        pathname: '/app/unauthorized',
        }}
      />
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: I mean, What did u change?

Comment: Omg... Ofc! Thanks! I didn't even catch that.

Comment: Always provide an explanation for what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You do not return component in a render function:

```
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={ props => {
      /// THERES NO RETURN STATEMENT ...
      user[0].tier > 1
      ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: '/app/unauthorized',
        }}
      />
      )
    }}
  />
```